# dynamic sitemap generator for Nancy app

Tags: c#, .net, sitemap, nancy

I have a Nancy web site and I am looking for a dynamic site map generator.

There are plenty of site map generation examples out there but all those I have looked at involve some kind of manual update such as this one for MVC:

```
new SitemapItem(Url.QualifiedAction("index", "home"), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Always, priority: 1.0),
```

If I have to update the code every time I add a view then I might as well use an online generator tool or add the new page to a static file instead.

Is anyone aware of a method that could scan nancy modules for routes and generate a sitemap on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I've written mine by hand and honestly not sure how you can automate it on the server without application knowledge. The exception would be something with just static routes, as most applications use a variety of parameter-based routes (e.g. /item/{id}). Nancy doesn't know or care about the id value, so you can't ask it to provide a list of valid urls. As you mentioned, aside from writing a custom module in Nancy you can also use an external tool to crawl the site to generate it for you.